# Audited Gem current_user_method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-audited

I am using the Audited gem in my application for tracking user log. Everything is working fine except for current user tracking.

In my case, I have 2 models: `Instructor` and `Student`. `Instructor` will be the `current_admin_user`, and I need to find the student manually.

To overcome this issue, I tried to override `current_user_method` and create an audited.rb file in the initializers with below content:

```
Audited.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

This is working fine, but when I use any other method like `current_user_or_student` ...

```
Audited.current_user_method = :current_user_or_student
```

in `application_controller.rb` ...

```
def current_user_or_student
  current_admin_user || InstructorStudent.find_by_id(id)
end
```

it is not going into this method, even `current_admin_user` is also not storing in audits.

Why isn't my `current_user_or_student` method being called when overriding it in `application_controller.rb`?

Comment: I checked your github profile, but I do not know which project are you talking about

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio this project is not in my github profile. Do you need project to solve my problem ?

Comment: can you share the detailed logs.

Comment: I dont have any log, but when i user `current_admin_user` in audited.rb, it is storing user perfactly, when i use custom method `current_user_or_student` it is not storing. even exit is also not working for that method

Comment: Can you provide the source of `current_admin_user`? Are you setting `Audited.current_user_method` in an initializer? Or are you attempting to change it dynamically at runtime?

Comment: @DerekPrior I setting `Audited.current_user_method` in audited.rb initializer. It is working fine. because current_admin_user is method of devise. i want to customize method like when current admin user change details it should show current_admin_user, but when any student change details it should show student changed detail. student is just model it is not resource of devise and instructor is resource of devise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I resolved my issue, I am using STI (single table inheritance) .
my other controllers of instructor was not inherite from application controller. so my `current_user_or_student` was not called for instructor login .

To overcome this issue, i create one  controller concern called `audited_user.rb`

and write following method in concern

```
def current_user_or_student
  current_admin_user || InstructorStudent.find_by_id(id)
end
```

and included this concern in both my instructor base controller and application controller. 
now everything is working fine and my audited user is also save correctly.

I hope this will save any others day.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `current_user_or_student` as such:

```
def current_user_or_student
  current_admin_user || InstructorStudent.find_by_id(id)
end
```

Assuming `current_admin_user` is `nil`, it will try to find `InstructorStudent`. You are using `find_by_id` which will return `nil` if the `InstructorStudent` with that id cannot be found. It's likely that is what is happening. It's not clear from this source what `id` is -- are you sure it's set to an id that can be found in `instructor_students`? I would encourage you to do the following to debug:

```
def current_user_or_student
  current_admin_user || InstructorStudent.find(id)
end
```

This will raise an error if the method's conditional falls through to the `InstructorStudent.find` branch and the `id` cannot be found. If my hypothesis is correct, this will prove that the id cannot be found, so your original code is returning `nil` (while this updated code now errors instead). The error message will also tell you what the value of `id` is which you can use for further debugging.

Alternatively, you can debug this without changing code by running a request that you expect to be audited but isn't and then inspecting the server logs. You will see the queries run there and may be able to debug that way as well.

Comment: i think i already resolved this issue, i just need to add before_action :current_user_or_student ,in application_controller.rb everything else was working fine. and now it is also working fine

Comment: It is not working in that way, i dont what is wrong with my application controller, even `  before_filter :audited_user`  is also not working . and it is not calling before any action :(